# $(\mathbb{F}[T] \ / \ P^2 \mathbb{F}[T])^*$ cyclic if and only if $\text{deg}(P)=1$ where $P$ is an irreducible polynomial over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I am asked to prove that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field of size $p$ prime and $P\in \mathbb{F}[T]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$ then $(\mathbb{F}[T] \ / \ P^2 \mathbb{F}[T])^*$ is cyclic if and only if the degree of $P$ is 1.

For one direction I used Proposition 1.6 from Michael Rosen's Number Theory in Function Fields which states that if the group $G$ is the kernel of the natural map $(A \ / \ P^e A)^* \rightarrow (A \ / \ PA)^*$ (where $A = \mathbb{F}[T]$) the follow inequality holds:

$$ d \geq \frac{\text{deg}(P)(e-1)}{s}$$

Where $d$ is the minimal number of generators of $G$ and $s$ is the smallest integer such that $p^s\geq e$. As in this case $e=2$ we would have that $s=1$ and therefore $d \geq \text{deg}(P)$. So if $\text{deg}(P)\neq 1$ then $d \geq 2$, therefore $G$ wouldn't be cyclic and neither would $(A \ / \ P^2A)^*$.

But I am struggling to prove that if $\text{deg}(P)=1$ then $(A \ / \ P^2A)^*$ is cyclic. I thought about using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups as that same proposition says that the size of $(A \ / \ P^2A)^*$ is $p \cdot (p-1)$ but I don't think that would take anywhere. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $P$ is irreducible of degree $\ge 2$ then the image of $1+P(T) \Bbb{F}_p[T]$ in $(\Bbb{F}_p[T]/(P(T)^2))^\times$ is a $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space of dimension $\deg(P)$, so it is not cyclic. A finite group having a non-cyclic subgroup isn't cyclic.

Comment: This answers (a generalization of) your question: [Multiplicative group modulo polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956919/multiplicative-group-modulo-polynomials). See also the case $m=2$ of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515575), and the first comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483642). @reuns yes but the question was about the converse.

Comment: Nice call, @AnneBauval !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to examine explicitly the structure of $\mathbb{F}[T]/(P^2\mathbb{F}[T])$: reduce to the case where $P=T$, and then one sees that
$$
\mathbb{F}[T]/(T^2\mathbb{F}[T])=\{c+d\epsilon\mid c,d\in\mathbb{F}\}
$$
with $\epsilon$ being the class of $T$ in the quotient. Now try to see what the multiplicative structure looks like. What are the units of this ring? What is $(c+d\epsilon)^n$ for arbitrary $c,d\in\mathbb{F}$? Use this to explicitly find a generator of $(\mathbb{F}[T]/(T^2\mathbb{F}[T]))^*$ (in terms of a generator of $\mathbb{F}^*$).

> If $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}^*$ then $g+\epsilon$ generates $(\mathbb{F}[T]/(T^2\mathbb{F}[T]))^*$. Indeed, $(g+\epsilon)^n=g^n+ng^{n-1}\epsilon$ is equal to $1$ if and only if both $c^n=1$ and $nc^{n-1}=0$. These two imply that $(p-1)p$ divides $n$, so the order of $g+\epsilon$ is $(p-1)p$